# Prompting user to enter string for acronym program

Tags: c++, string

The program prompts the user to enter a phrase and will then create an acronym from the words. Unlike a traditional acronym which has capital letters, the case of the letters remain the same. If I were to enter *The Town Hall is old*, I should get **TTHio**. How can I use isspace to make sure my program runs properly since it does not combine the characters if there are more than one blank spaces next to each other? It can't handle tabs either.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <cctype> 
using namespace std; 
string create_acronym(string str); 
int main()
{
    cout << "This program tests the acronym function." << "\n"; 
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter a string: "; 
        string str; 
        getline(cin, str); 
        if (str == "") 
        {
            break; 
        }
        cout << "\n\nThe acronym is \"" << create_acronym(str) << "\"" << "\n";
    } 
    return 0;
}
string create_acronym(string str) 
{
    string acronym = "";
    acronym = str.at(0); 
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        if (str.at(i) == ' ') 
        {
            acronym += str.at(i+1); 
        }
    }
    return acronym; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that you need to output the next non-space:

```
string create_acronym( const string & str ) 
{
    string acronym;
    bool use_next = true;        

    for ( char c : str )
    {
        bool space = isspace(c);
        if ( use_next && !space ) acronym += c;
        use_next = space;
    }
    return acronym; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, paddy. I am confused about the char c.

Comment: That's a range-based loop.  If you aren't compiling with C++11, you can do `for( int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ )` and then use `str[i]` instead of `c`.  Note that there's no point using `.at` because `i` is guaranteed to be in range.